# Java check directory for zip files

Tags: java, android, directory, if-statement, zip

I have the below code which checks to see if folder exists on the sdcard, I would like to add another if statement if the folder exists to check that there are zip files inside the actual folder if it in fact exists. What could i do to check the folder for a zip extension. The folder should have a lot of zips in it but i only want it to check to make sure there are zips and no other file extension. I thank you for any help with this.

```
File z = new File("/mnt/sdcard/folder");
if(!z.exists()) {
Toast.makeText(MainMethod.this, "/sdcard/folder Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
} else {
Toast.makeText(MainMethod.this, "/sdcard/folder Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks guys for the help here is what i ended up using with your help, i haven't tested it yet but it looks good to me.

```
    File z = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Folder");
    if(!z.exists()) {
           //create folder
} else {
        FilenameFilter f2 = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return filename.endsWith("zip");
        }
        };
            if (z.list(f2).length > 0) {
            // there's a zip file in there..
            } else {
            //no zips inside folder
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
File f = new File("folder");
FilenameFilter f2 = new FilenameFilter() {
public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
return filename.endsWith("zip");
}
};
if (f.list(f2).length > 0) {
// there's a zip file in there..
}
```

Try the above..

Comment: Hey I am getting error message "Attempt to get length of null array" at the if statement there. Do you have any ideas why is it so?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [`FileNameFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) ?

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/folder");
if(e.exist()){//file exist ??

File[] matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith("zip");
    }
});//list out files with zip at the end

}
```