# How to get ftl files from directory and subdirectry

Tags: java

I want to get complete list of ftl file from directory and their subdirectory with their relative path. For example suppose if I have a ftl file in `D:\abc\pqr\lmn\try.ftl` and I pass `D:\abc` as search path then I should get `/pqr/lmn/try.ftl` and all `*.ftl` files list which are present in search directory and their subdirectory with relative path as result.

Can someone help me achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pass dir to your method
- List out all the direct sub dir of the passed dir [*and look for the file with fileName using*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235177/java-check-directory-for-zip-files/5235239#5235239) `FileNameFilter`
- recursively call this for all the sub dir

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
        String dir = TEMPLATE_PATH;
        File folder = new File(dir);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                         if (listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".ftl") || listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".FTL"))
                         {
                                System.out.println("[FILE]" + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                                fileName.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());


                         }
                    } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {

                    String directoryToSearch = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    System.out.println("[DIR]" + directoryToSearch);

                    File subFolder = new File(dir + directoryToSearch);
                    File[] listOfSubFiles = subFolder.listFiles();
                    for (int j = 0; j < listOfSubFiles.length; j++){
                         if (listOfSubFiles[j].getName().endsWith(".ftl") || listOfSubFiles[j].getName().endsWith(".FTL"))
                         {
                            System.out.println("\t[DIR]" + listOfSubFiles[j].getName());
                             fileName.add(listOfSubFiles[j].getName());


                         }
                    }

                    }
                }
```